# I don't know why the division produces a quotient and a remainder that are wrong

Tags: assembly, x86-16, division, tasm, dosbox

How to fix this one: I don't know why both the quotient and the remainder are wrong.

My DOSBox Code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

Dividend        db 0dh,0ah,"Enter Dividend    : $"  ;string
Divisor         db 0dh,0ah,"Enter Divisor     : $"
Quotient        db 0dh,0ah,"Display Quotient  : $"
Remainder       db 0dh,0ah,"Display Remainder : $"

.code
main proc   ;main program here
            
mov ax,@data                ;initialize ds
mov ds,ax
            
mov ah,09h                  ;Show Enter Dividend
lea dx, Dividend
int 21h
            
mov ah,01h                  ;Input Dividend
int 21h
mov bh,al
            
mov ah,09h                  ;Show Enter Divisor
lea dx, Divisor
int 21h
            
mov ah,01h                  ;Input Divisor
int 21h
mov bl,al
            
mov ah,00h                  ;Divide
mov al,bh
div bl
mov cx,ax
add cx,3030h
            
mov ah,09h                  ;Show Display Quotient
lea dx, Quotient
int 21h
            
mov ah,02                   ;Display Quotient
mov dl,cl
int 21h
            
mov ah,09h                  ;Show Display Remainder
lea dx, Remainder
int 21h
            
mov ah,02                   ;Display Remainder
mov dl,ch
int 21h
            
mov ah,4Ch                  ;end here
int 21h
            
main endp
end main
```

Error Result:

> ```
> Enter Dividend    : 7
> Enter Divisor     : 3
> Display Quotient  : 1
> Display Remainder : 4
> ```

Comment: nope i'am from phillipines

Comment: Single-stepping with a debugger will show you register values, which will make it obvious why those are the division results.  And push the mystery back to why you have those numbers in registers in the first place, hopefully in a way that jogs your memory or leads you to google something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange results that you show us stem from the fact that the program executes the division 55 / 51 which will indeed produce a quotient of 1 and a remainder of 4.

The DOS.GetCharacter function 01h that you use for input returns an ASCII code in `AL`. When you push <kbd>7</kbd> on the keyboard, the `AL` register will hold the ASCII code 37h or 55 in decimal. Before using this input in a calculation you need to convert from character into the value that the digit represents. A simple `sub al, 30h` does that. Of course you need to do the same thing for the second input too:

```
...
mov ah, 09h                  ;Show Enter Dividend
lea dx, Dividend
int 21h
            
mov ah, 01h                  ;Input Dividend
int 21h
sub al, 30h
mov bh, al
            
mov ah, 09h                  ;Show Enter Divisor
lea dx, Divisor
int 21h
            
mov ah, 01h                  ;Input Divisor
int 21h
sub al, 30h
mov bl, al
...
```

Comment: okay i get it now